# How to append '#' to the value in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Can anyone please help me how to append '#' to the value as below:

My code is below:

```
var idselvalue = '#'+idvalue;
console.log("IDSELVALUE"+idselvalue); // Printing as ::: #"T2"
```

( I want this to be printed as "#T2" so that I want to include the below)

```
 $('#idselvalue').val(usrObj); // to display the selected option in the select box
```

if I hard the value as below:

```
 $('#T2').val("26");
```

I also need help how to retrieve all the selected options, as of now I'm able to get only one first selected option

Below is my code:::

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            var usrObj = getCookie("selectedEXP");
            var idvalue = getCookie("selectedIDValue");


            var idselvalue = '#'+idvalue;
            console.log("IDSELVALUE"+idselvalue);
          $('#idselvalue').val(usrObj);

            console.log("OnLoad Calling usrObj"+usrObj);
            console.log("OnLoad Calling idvalue"+idvalue);

//Printing only one selected options
});
```

Appreciate your help! Thanks in advance :)

Comment: var idselvalue = '#'+idvalue; 
console.log("IDSELVALUE"+idselvalue); / Printing as ::: #"T2"
( I want this to be printed as "#T2" so that I want to include the below)
$('#idselvalue').val(usrObj); // to display the selected option in the select box

Comment: `$('#idselvalue').val(usrObj);` should be `$(idselvalue)` you already appended a `#` to the beginning and js can't determine the var from the string, it will just treat the entire thing as a string.

Comment: Initially I want to append '#' to idvalue in declaration as below:

$(document).ready(function () {     var usrObj = getCookie("selectedEXP");     var idvalue = getCookie("selectedIDValue");       var idselvalue = '#'+idvalue;

Comment: Can you show us the getCookie method? If you are having such issues, I am wondering if it is placing the quotes actually within the string.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following:

```
var idselvalue = function(d){return "#"+idvalue;}
```

along with *scrappedcola*'s suggestion:

> $('#idselvalue').val(usrObj); should be $(idselvalue) you already appended a # to the beginning and js can't determine the var from the string, it will just treat the entire thing as a string.

Comment: the declaration of that variable in the ready function, how to invoke other function?
it is printing….

return "#"+idvalue;

Comment: Call that function using idselvalue(). So you would have: 
    console.log("IDSELVALUE"+idselvalue()); 
Not sure if its a good idea to use functions to return a value, but it seems to work for me.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work...
 Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #"T2"

I want to append ‘#’ to idvalue, In the below code when I tried appending it is printing

 #”T2” instead of “#T2”

Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it by removing the double quotes for the idvalue and userobj as below:

```
 var idselvalue = '#'+idvalue.replace(/\"/g, "");
            var selusrObj = usrObj.replace(/\"/g, "");
            $(idselvalue).val(selusrObj);
```

It is working fine...

Thank you!